# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to activate SWRevealViewController pan gesture

Tags: ios, user-interface, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController for sidebars and I have to use swipe for my previous and next stories and edge pan for sidebars.

The reason I use UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer instead of PanGestureRecogniser is because swipe will end up call pan gesture which causes the whole page a mess. I hoping there is a way to call pan gesture when edge pan recogniser activated instead of using this:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[MainViewController sharedInstance].revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];


[[BTHomeViewController sharedInstance].revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: left];
[[BTHomeViewController sharedInstance].revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: right];
```

I want to use delegate of SWRevealVC. If there is any other way, please suggest it to me.

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *panLeft = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_handleRevealGesture:)];
[panLeft setEdges:UIRectEdgeLeft];
panLeft.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
panLeft.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panLeft];
```

Delegate Methods of SWRevealVC

```
// The following methods provide a means to track the evolution of the gesture recognizer.
// The 'location' parameter is the X origin coordinate of the front view as the user drags it
// The 'progress' parameter is a positive value from 0 to 1 indicating the front view location relative to the
// rearRevealWidth or rightRevealWidth. 1 is fully revealed, dragging ocurring in the overDraw region will result in values above 1.
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController panGestureBeganFromLocation:(CGFloat)location progress:(CGFloat)progress;
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController panGestureMovedToLocation:(CGFloat)location progress:(CGFloat)progress;
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController panGestureEndedToLocation:(CGFloat)location progress:(CGFloat)progress;
```

Answer (score 5):

To replace UIPanGestureRecognizer with UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer just do this:

- Go to SWRevealViewController
- Find and replace UIPanGestureRecognizer with
  UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer
- Most IMPORTANT set edges

  _panGestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;

Comment: I did this however it comes with a downfall I must say. When you want to close the screen menu by swiping it doesn't work.

Also I'm noticing that the menu will collapse when you expand it over the point where it will snap to